# GLM: assign 3x3 sub matrix of 4x4 matrix

Tags: c++, glm-math

Let's say I have a 4x4 matrix `M` and a 3x3 matrix `R`.

How can write the 3x3 submatrix of M with R?

The naive way would be using two loops:

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        M[i][j] = R[i][j];
    }
}
```

But I would like to know if there is a shorthand for this in GLM.

EDIT:

Someone pointed out there is a similar question: [Simplest way to convert mat3 to mat4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47225368/simplest-way-to-convert-mat3-to-mat4)

But it's not the same because, in that question, the 4th row&col are filled with the pattern of the identity matrix. But I need to preserve the original contents of the 4th row&col of M

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simplest way to convert mat3 to mat4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47225368/simplest-way-to-convert-mat3-to-mat4)

Comment: No, because I need to preserve the contents of of the 4th row and column